# what does && return in javascript expression

Tags: javascript

I was reading the javascipt code in some application and code was this

```
getTotalFees:function(){
        return this.grid
        &&this.grid.getStore().sum('fees');
}
```

Now i am confused what it will return.

IT looks to me like

`return a&&b`

won't it return true or false rather than b

Comment: If `a` is not `undefined` and `b` is not `undefined`, return `b`.

Comment: That code is functionally equivalent to `if (this.grid) { return this.grid.getStore().sum('fees');}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Logical AND (`&&`):
>   `expr1 && expr2` Returns `expr1` if it can be converted to false; otherwise, returns `expr2`. Thus, when used with Boolean values, `&&` returns `true` if both operands are `true`; otherwise, returns `false`.

[**Source**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Description)

So, basically:
If the first parameter is `falsy`, it returns that parameter. Else, it literally returns the second parameter.

In your case, this means that, if `this.grid` exists, it returns `this.grid.getStore().sum('fees');`

Comment: if grid does not exist will it return `False` or `this.grid` which is `undefined`

Comment: It will then return `this.grid`, which is `undefined `, a [`falsy`](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/) value.

Comment: and it will not even try to call `this.grid.getStore().sum('fees');`, thus avoiding errors

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand what `&&` does. Let `a` and `b` be "entities". Then `a && b` does:

1. evaluate `a`
2. if `a` is falsy return `a`
3. if `a` is truthy evaluate `b`
4. return `b`

Example:

```
var f = function() {
    console.log("test");
    return 'foo';
}

> 0 && f()
0
> 1 && f()
test
"foo"
```

Note that in first case we didn't get `console.log` because `f()` was not evaluated because `0` is falsy. This property is important and actually

```
a && b != b && a
```

even though mathematically it should be the same (but it is not due to side-effects of evaluation).

Falsy values include: `0`, `false`, `""` (empty string), `null`, `undefined`,`NaN` (not a number type). I don't think there are any other possible values (someone correct me if I'm wrong). Every other object is truthy.

So in your case the code can be rewritten as:

```
if (this.grid) {
    return this.grid.getStore().sum('fees');
} else {
    return this.grid;
}
```

Comment: 3. if `a`is defined not truthy, or better if it is not `undefined`

Comment: @algorhythm `"" && 2 === ""` while obviously `""` is defined.

Comment: "" is falsy, as are 0 and 'false'

Comment: @algorhythm Yes, that's exactly what I've written. Empty string is falsy.

Comment: @Boris yes, but it's not `undefined` and I commented "..., or better if it is not undefined"

Comment: @algorhythm It doesn't matter what's undefined or not. Only falsy, truthy matters.

Comment: @freakish If a expression is defined and you ask for `!undefined` than it is `true`

Comment: @algorhythm I have no idea what you're talking about and how this is related to what I've written.

Answer (score 1):

This is done to protect against calling a method on undefined property, witch would cause an error. So if `this.grid` is `undefined`, then `undefined` is returned.

In expressions if `a && b` when `a` equals to `false` (or in javascript it can be an expression like in Cerburs answer), then `a` is returned.

Similarly with `||` operator, the first from the left that equals to `true` (in javascript not 0, not undefined, not null, not NaN, and not false of course) is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's assume that `this.grid.getStore().sum('fees')` returns something, let's say "okay!".

now the return statement in your code is a convoluted way of saying :

```
if(this.grid)//this.grid is defined and doesn't evaluate as 'false'
    return this.grid.getStore().sum('fees');
else
    return this.grid;
```

if this hasn't got a grid, we return undefined, else we call `gridStore...` and return its own return. 
It is a common way of avoiding "undefined has no method 'gridStore'"

the VERY important part is that, in `a && f()`, f() will NOT be called if 'a' evaluates to false. there are many things that evaluate to false, such as any undefined variable, `null`,  empty strings... (note that strings that contain falsy things like `"false"` or `"0000"` are actually truthy). or even unreadable babble like  `function(){return null;}();` may evaluate as false.

Comment: Actually that's not the same code. The `if` statement should be `if (this.grid)`. Otherwise it does different thing (what if `this.grid` is `0`?).

Comment: yes you're right, or `if(!!this.grid)`. but i thought it would be more comprehensible. i'll edit